# Unit Testing a function dealing with database records

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

Unit tests should only test the logic of one function and should "mock" the data that is used in that function. I am wondering how would we unit the following function with "mocking" the data? or even if its the correct way. The function signature is

```
    public String doSomething(int firstId, int secondId, int count){
     //this function looks in a table e.g. C which has foreign keys from table A, and B
    //if firstId and secondId exist in db table C return "already-exists"
    //if count < a_column_value_in_table_C return "not-allow"
    // else return "success"
    }
```

The `firstId` and `secondId` are foreign keys form two different tables. Now, how do we go about unit testing this function in terms of:
1. how the unit test should be design so it is able to test 3 scnarios in the function
2. how do we prepare data for this unit test given that it will need foreign keys from two different tables.

Comment: "*`//this function looks in a table e.g. C...`*" - How does this function do that? I would presume through some JDBC layer, e.g. a CRUD repository? If so: mock and inject this layer --- "*... so it is able to test 3 scnarios ..."* - Three scenarios, three different test, three different mocks.

Comment: hi @Turing85 at the moment the test classes are using the "real" repositories, it makes sense to work with mock repositories, I still dont fully understand how would this work but I will look into it but your approach makes sense to use mock crud depos

Answer (score 3):

You should be using dependency injection from Solid principles.
The class who owner of doSomething method should inject some Repository or DAO etc.

In your unit tests, you should mock repository methods.

For example, lets assume your doSomething method calls findById(...) method of repository. You should mock findById method by desired output and just test the logical part of your flow.

Answer (score 2):

I usually create a repository-interface with the getById and a getAll function. For testing purpose I create an inmemory-repository and for production I use the database-repository.

Here an example:

```
public interface Repository<T> {
  public T getById(int Id);
  public List<T> getAll();
}

public InmemoryRepository implements Repository<User> {
 List<User> database = new ArrayList<>(); //with some data
 public List<User> getAll() { 
  return database;
 }
 public User get(int Id) {
   return database.stream().filter(x -> x.Id = Id).collect(Collectors.asList());
 }
}
```

In your function you inject this repository so that you can access the database over:

```
public String doSomething(int firstId, int secondId, int count, Repository<User> repo){};
```

Comment: If this answer helped you please mark it as accepted. if not, please clarify it further for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some test database or in-memory one (like HSQLDB). Populate it with some test data before test (in method annotated `@BeforeClass` or during test datasource initialization if you use Spring). Then execute tests for all your scenarios passing prepared data. Cleanup data in test database in method annotated with `@AfterClass`.

In case you use Spring and configuration in XML config for test dataSource could look like this:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" >
  <jdbc:script location="scripts/ddl/*"/> <!-- create tables -->
  <jdbc:script location="scripts/dml/*"/> <!-- populate test data -->
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not supposed to design one unit test to match all the cases there is. For each case create a different unit test.
2. You need to mock the repository or class that access the database so that it will not execute in the database and instead it will return a result set predetermined by you in the unit test. There are mocking libraries for that, which makes your work very easy. If the code is only executing a query or procedure and returning the result back, there is not much merit in writing a unit test for it, writing an integration test should be enough in that case imo.

P.S: Emre Savcı, dependency injection is not a solid principle, dependency inversion is. They are not related at all.